# How to run :connect (local)

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run the following on SQL Server 2008 R2, I am getting `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ':'.` What is wrong?

```
:CONNECT(local)  
Go

USE msdb  
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable SQLCMD mode in SSMS.  Click on the Query drop down menu, then select "SQLCMD Mode".  Then you can run the query.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis around local and the GO on that line.  Also, GO statements should be on separate lines by themselves (which I see you had in your source and was just a formatting abnormality).

```
:CONNECT local
USE msdb
GO
```

Comment: The syntax is good, I have to enable cmd mode to execute cmd commands